# Can "assign()" and "get()" be written more concisely?

Tags: r

Below is my code. I use an extra variation "tmp" to clean the "ABC_Chla". Because the "Location_name" can change, I use  "assign()" and "get()" function.

```
Location_name <- "ABC_"
tmp <- get(paste(Location_name,"DO",sep = "")) %>% filter(log.DO != -Inf)
assign(paste(Location_name,"DO",sep = ""), tmp)
```

My code can achieve this goal, but it seems not concise (introduce a temporary variable). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the inputs shown reproducibly in the Note at the end (next time please make sure your question includes complete reproducible code including inputs) we can make the following changes:

- use `paste0` instead of `paste`
- create a variable `locname` to hold the name of the data frame and a variable `e` to be the environment where our data frame is located
- use `e[[...]]` instead of `get` and `assign`
- use magrittr `%<>%` two-way pipe
- possibly use `filter(is.finite(log.DO))` -- not shown below

giving this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

e <- .GlobalEnv # change if our data frame is in some other environment
locname <- paste0(Location_name, "DO")

e[[locname]] %<>% 
   filter(log.DO != -Inf)
```

The result is:

```
get(locname, e)
##   log.DO
## 1      1
## 2      2
```

### Alternative

This alternative only uses ordinary pipes. We use `e` and `locname` from above.

```
library(dplyr)

 e[[locname]] <- e[[locname]] %>% 
  filter(log.DO != -Inf)
```

### Note

Test input:

```
ABC_DO <- data.frame(log.DO = c(1, -Inf, 2))
Location_name <- "ABC_"
```

Comment: Amazing! Your every suggestion helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You only have a temporary variable because you store the data in tmp, i don't see it as a problem.But, n this case, the only thing that i see you can do is pass the code of tmp directly to assign, like:

```
assign(
       paste(Location_name,"DO",sep = ""),
       get(paste(Location_name,"DO",sep = "")) %>% filter(log.DO != -Inf)
      )
```